# PROTOBUFF INT64 check aganist previously entered data c++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net, protobuf-c

```
message HealthOccurrenceCount
{
    required int64 HealthID=1; 
    required int32 OccCount=2; 
    optional bytes wci=3;
}
```

I would like to add data based on `HealthID`; If `HealthID` is already entered then instead of adding a new entry, the program should instead just increment the existing entry's `OccCount`.

```
HealthOccurrenceCount objHelthOccCount;
if(objHelthOccCount.healthid() == healthID) // Is this right or do I need to iterate all the nodes?
{
    occCount++;  
    objHelthOccCount.set_occcount(occCount);  
}
else       
    occCount = 1;
```

Is this code correct or I should convert `HealthID` into string?

Generated Code:

```
// required int64 HealthID = 1;
inline bool has_healthid() const;
inline void clear_healthid();
static const int kHealthIDFieldNumber = 1;
inline ::google::protobuf::int64 healthid() const;
inline void set_healthid(::google::protobuf::int64 value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial) there is a has_ methods for each singular (required or optional) field which return true if that field has been set.

Your code would then be something like:

```
        HealthOccurrenceCount objHelthOccCount;
        if(objHelthOccCount.has_healthid())
        {
            occCount++;  
            objHelthOccCount.set_occcount(occCount);  
        }
        else       
            occCount = 1;
```